# Periodic BC for Multigrid in MD

Tags: multigrid, molecular-dynamics

I know that this question might be very specific and maybe nobody will know the answer, but this is probably the only community where I could find an answer:

So, as part of my master's project, I am currently writing a multigrid code for Poisson's equation in order to calculate particle interactions in a molecular dynamcis setup. I'd like to use periodic BCs, but here arises one problem:

According to the Multigrid book by Trottenberg, periodic BCs only have a solution if $\sum_{x, y, z} f_h(x,y,z) = 0$, where $f_h$ is the right hand side and the sum is over all gridpoints.

The algorithm I found in some publications samples the charged particles via a density function to the grid. So in general, even if the total charge of the system is neutral, this condition will not be fulfilled.

Unfortunately, all papers I found only deal with this PBC problem on a quick sidenote and I wasn't able to get any valuable information out of it.

The code I wrote so far produced fine results when using different functions which fulfill this condition, but fails when going to the real data, i.e., sampled particle charge densities. My question now: Does anybody know this problem and the solution, or any idea which could help me?

Comment: Hi @chris, and welcome to Scicomp!  I'm curious... Are you using *purely* periodic boundary conditions?

Comment: Hey and thank you. Yes I am. It is a conventional way when using FFT based methods such as SPME or P3M, so I also want to have periodic BCs to be able to compare the results

Comment: What kind of function are you using to map your particles to the grid? Do they preserve the sum of the quantity you are mapping?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't a multigrid issue, it's a problem formulation issue. Consider the symmetric system $A x = b$ and suppose that $A e = 0$ for some nonzero vector $e$ (the constant when $A$ is the Laplacian with periodic or Neumann boundary conditions). This system is singular and has no solution if you choose $b$ such that $e^T b \ne 0$. Indeed, the exact periodic problem is ill-posed because the integral of the Coulomb potential with some periodic change density (not averaging to zero) over all space is infinite. That is, if $\sigma(r')$ is periodic with nonzero integral, then

$$\Phi (r) = \int_{r'\in R^3} \frac{\sigma(r')}{4 \pi \vert r - r'\rvert} \mathrm{d} r' = \pm \infty .$$

Fortunately, all that matters is the field, not the potential, so you can renormalize. This amounts to projecting out the null space by solving

$$ A x = (I - e e^T) b $$

where $e$ is the normalized null space vector.

Comment: Thank you, this works. Just for my personal understanding: Why can we introduce this shift of $b$ without affecting the field?

Comment: The field $F = \nabla \Phi = \nabla (\Phi + C)$ for any constant $C$.